# Show children of page in custom menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom menu structure created using Appearance > Menu

When on a page I would like to show a menu inside of the page containing all menu items that are children of that page in the custom menu. I can only get wp_get_nav() to display all pages and currently my solution is to use css to hide the other menu items which works but is not particularly elegant.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: If you want something to appear in the sidebar you can use **Child Page Navigation** plugin in the repo on wordpress.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Child Pages Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/child-pages-shortcode/) - Once this plugin is installed and activated, simply place the shortcode it gives you where you’d like your list of child pages to appear (e.g. at the bottom of the content on your Parent Page).

[List Pages Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-pages-shortcode/) - Inserting the shortcode [child-pages] will give you a simple list like the following:

[image]

Please test [RVSubMenu plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rv-submenus/), see if it works for you. It's outdated, but should work perfectly. You may not want to use a widget, so look for a plugin to display widgets in your page (check out [AMR Shortcode Any Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/)).

Here might be a resourceful link I found after a swift search using keywords - `children menu items + wordpress`

[Some dude made a cool post](http://scottlee.me/current-page-sub-menu/) about your topic - check it out.